# having jasmine error on npm install, angular4

Tags: angular

I am trying to run npm install, on angular-4 project , it is giving me error,

My package.json is:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.6",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.3",
```

and

```
"typescript": "~2.3.3" in dependencies.


ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,227): ':' expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,47): ';' expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,104): ']' expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,112): ',' expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,113): Property assignment expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,121): ')' expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,147): '(' expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,162): ']' expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,163): ',' expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,164): Property assignment expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,165): Property assignment expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,179): ',' expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,183): ':' expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,208): '{' expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,217): ':' expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,222): ',' expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,90): '(' expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,228): Expression expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,230): ')' expected.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,68): 'ReadonlyArray' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,92): The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,94): Cannot find name 'methodName'.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,106): Cannot find name 'string'.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,124): 'ReadonlyArray' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,149): The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,150): A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,151): Cannot find name 'P'.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,156): Cannot find name 'keyof'.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,162): Cannot find name 'T'.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,180): Cannot find name 'P'.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,217): Cannot find name 'T'.
ERROR in /home/infinity/CiscoGit/AS/AS-BAC-BPA/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts (138,219): Cannot find name 'P'.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the following [semver](https://semver.org/) in your `package.json` for the @types/jasmine package:

```
"@types/jasmine": "^2.8.3"
```

The `^` implies that your package installer will download the latest minor version that's out there available for the said package, which in this case is 2.8.11. (If you visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jasmine you will notice that they released their latest version 2.8.11 20 hours ago.)

There are two ways to go about solving your problem:
1) Make sure your Typescript version is compatible with the @types/jasmine package
2) Lock down your version to a specific one (2.8.8 is fairly stable).
Hope this helps!

Comment: Locking to 2.8.8 sorted it for me.

Comment: i hv same issue, my @types/jasmine version : ^3.3.12, typescript: ~2.6.2. but how can i check which typescript version that can work with jasmine 3.3.12 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `@types/jasmine` version to `"@types/jasmine": "2.5.38"` and reinstall.

[Here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/14569) you can find a long discussion about it.

Comment: I tried this, not working, but it was working few days back

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error and locked the jasmine version to the latest working version, which for me was

```
"@types/jasmine": "2.8.9"
```

However, i ran into another issue because I am using karma-jasmine-html-reporter

https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-html-reporter

So I locked the version for this package as well to the latest working version, which for me was

```
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.3.1"
```

After these two changes the build was working again for me.

Be sure to remove the locks once another working version of jasmine and karma-jasmine-html-reporter comes out.